# Moving the ball with pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Hey guys am developing a bounce ball like game with pygame. .. I have downloaded an image `ball.jpg` which acts like a ball and `bg.jpg` which is the background..I have tried to move the ball.But it didnt works .My code is

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
clocks = pygame.time.Clock()
surfaceObject = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
pygame.display.set_caption('Bounce')

mousey,mousex = 0,0
imgx = 10
imgy = 10
pixmove = 5
movement = 'down'


background = pygame.image.load('bg.jpg').convert()
ball = pygame.image.load('ball.jpg').convert_alpha()

sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('yeah.mp3')


while True:

if movement == 'down':
    imgx += pixmove
if imgy < 200:
    movement = 'right'

elif movement  == 'right':
    imgx += pixmove
if imgx < 200:
    movement = 'up'


elif movement == 'up':
    imgy -= pixmove
if imgy < 30:
    movement = 'left'


elif movement == 'left':
    imgx -= pixmove
if imgx < 30:
    movement = 'down'




for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()


        surfaceObject.blit(background,(mousex,mousey))
        surfaceObject.blit(ball,(imgx,imgy))
        sound.Play()


    pygame.display.update()
    clocks.tick(50)
```

When i run this code the image doesnt load on the pygame window ..I have saved the `bounce.py` in the the folder along with the two image which i have downloaded..

I want to move the ball and display the ball image and the background image on pygame window..Hope you guys can help me out ..Thanks in advance

Comment: I tested the code, the pygame window is loading. I think your facing indentation problems

Comment: @AshokaLella but it didnt show any errors ..

Comment: I was getting an error for `sound.Play()` as I dont have `yeah.mp3`. So I removed those lines. Apart form that I got a ball and background and the ball seems to be moving right

Comment: @AshokaLella oh i see ..do you have any idea on how can we play a sound as th background image.

Comment: @AshokaLella i have removed the sound lines and still i didnt get the ball and background image

Comment: @AshokaLella it will be great if you post the working code as an answer

Comment: this is what I've done(http://pastebin.com/eBKrHB3R). I'm running linux and python2.7. Let me know if its working for you as well. If so, I'll post the answer.

Comment: @AshokaLella when i pasted the same code on the python console and run it i got unexpected intentation error on the first line of code ..

Comment: @AshokaLella how can i solve this problem ..:(

Comment: Can you saving this (http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=eBKrHB3R) as a py file from your browser and run it?

Comment: @AshokaLella thanx a ton man ..this works perfect ..:D ...but how can i add sound ..?? i have added the line  sound.play() under surfaceObject.blit(ball,(imgx,imgy))  .but it didnt works ..do you have any idea how to aceheive this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed indentation issues in code:

```
import time                                              
import pygame, sys                                      
from pygame.locals import *                              
pygame.init()                                            
clocks = pygame.time.Clock()                            
surfaceObject = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))      
pygame.display.set_caption('Bounce')                    

mousey,mousex = 0,0                                      
imgx = 10                                                
imgy = 10                                                
pixmove = 5                                              
movement = 'down'                                        

background = pygame.image.load('bg.jpg').convert()      
ball = pygame.image.load('ball.jpg').convert_alpha()    
pygame.mixer.music.load('yeah.mp3')

while True:                                              
    time.sleep(1)                                        
    if movement == 'down':                              
        imgx += pixmove                                  
    if imgy < 200:                                      
        movement = 'right'                              

    elif movement  == 'right':                          
        imgx += pixmove                                  
    if imgx < 200:                                      
        movement = 'up'                                  


    elif movement == 'up':                              
        imgy -= pixmove                                  
    if imgy < 30:                                        
        movement = 'left'                                


    elif movement == 'left':                            
        imgx -= pixmove                                  
    if imgx < 30:                                        
        movement = 'down'                                
    print movement                                      
    print imgx                                          
    print imgy                                          

    for event in pygame.event.get():                    
        if event.type == QUIT:                          
            pygame.quit()                                
            sys.exit()                                  

    surfaceObject.blit(background,(mousex,mousey))      
    surfaceObject.blit(ball,(imgx,imgy))                
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    pygame.display.update()                              
    clocks.tick(50)
```

Comment: may i know why the sound didnt works ??...i have added the line sound.play() under surfaceObject.blit(ball,(imgx,imgy)) .but it didnt works ..do you have any idea how to aceheive this ??

Comment: @user3783784, Added sound

Comment: @user3783784, make sure you add this line `pygame.mixer.music.load('yeah.mp3')` before while loop and `pygame.mixer.music.play()` inside while loop and increase the time delay

Comment: ..wow this works fine ..Thanx a lot ..i have one more doubt too how can i increase the speed of animation ..i have tried clock.tick(60) ,,but still the ball moves slow as the same speed

Comment: @user3783784, try varying pixmove

Comment: Lealla ..yeah it change ..but see the image gets stuck at a particular part .. ..what i need is to continously move like a square ..i have tried changing like 60*pimvoe ..but it didnt work ..do you know how can i accomplish this ?

Comment: @user3783784, Sorry mate. I can't help you any furhter